# How to upload my code changes to GERRIT for code review

Tags: github, gerrit

My question is quite a basic one, but couldnt find any appropriate answer after searching a lot on net i.e

*How do i push my code into Gerrit for the first time and hence forth*

I have a git repository at [this](https://github.com/ismailbaig/LunchBoxUI)

I have cloned it in my local systesm **D:/code** drive. i have also mapped my github repo to [this](https://review.gerrithub.io/#/admin/projects/)

Now when i make changes in my local machine and push the code via *Github desktop*, I could see the changes reflected in GIT HUB repository but not in GERRIT.

What am i missing ?

Comment: @marc_s: Done thanks. I was justing trying to emphasize on the actual issue to get focus by making it bold. Anyhow have reverted.

Comment: How do you try to push to Gerrit ? Did you set up your env to push to Gerrit instead of Git Hub ?

Comment: you need to push the changes to gerrithub - http://tuhrig.de/working-with-gerrithub-io/